# How many ways to arrange the word "mathematics" to new words( including meaningless words) which contain four letters?

Tags: combinatorics

I have a problem with solving this problem when I do the school's exercises and I found that my teacher has a big mistake on this subject. She taught me that you can count the same letters as one. And I think that solution miss some case of the words. Thank you so much. And sorry for my English skill.

Comment: What do you think is the right answer? try inculing that

Comment: I don't know the right answer, but I can show that this solution is wrong by showing an example. If the problem is. If you have a set of alphabets "PAPAYA" , then find the total number of ways to arrange these alphabets to new words that contain three alphabets. Then the total words you can obtain from this method is one. That's obviously wrong. @Arjun

Comment: Well if i would do it(assuming the repeeition of alphabets is not allowed), $11\times10\times9\times8$ would be the answer, as to pick first word we have 11 options and for second we have 10 and so on

Comment: I think you over count on some cases. If you label number on the repeating alphabets. You count the case $PA_1A_2$ and $PA_1A_3$ as two words, but both are the same. @Arjun

Comment: Your English is good, but I'll make one correction that when you say "alphabet" you should say "letter" to refer to a letter of the alphabet. That one slip up does make it a bit hard to understand your question. Good Luck!

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You have $8$ distinct letters in "mathematics", $3$ of them repeated once. There are three cases:

1. Your word has $4$ distinct letters: $\frac{8!}{4!}=1680$ possibilities.
2. Your word has one repeated letter: $3$ choices for which letter is repeated, ${4 \choose 2}=6$ positions where the repeated letters can occur, $7\times6$ possibilities for the other letters: $$3\times 6\times 7\times 6=756$$
3. Two sets of repeated letters: 3 configurations and $3\times2$ choices for the letters: $3\times3\times 2=18$ possibilities.

Thus you have $2454$ possible words.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

We have a set of letters {m, a, t, h, e, i, c, s} that contains 8 letters. If repetition is not allowed, then $C^4_8$ is the answer. If repetition is allowed, then the answer is $8^4$.

Comment: It seems reasonable to assume that repetition is allowed up to the number of repetitions that occur in 'mathematics'.  So for instance you could use 'm' up to two times, but not more.

Comment: @paw88789 yep you are right. for that case, there is an answer in the comments section.